# Merging multiple rows into one row in another sheet by joining two tables

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to merge two sheets, but the problem is the value I need to merge is split into a few rows in table 1 - [image](https://i.gyazo.com/173021a254097d8bdb4251d77327feac.png).

so I need it to sum the value column into one in table 2 - [image](https://i.gyazo.com/895cd072f763ca687897d0044cd48783.png).

I can map one to one, but I am lost at merging multiple into one

I looked for identical problems, but most are done via SQL.

Since this will have to be done on an already generated report I can't handle this on SQL level and need to find the solution post generation in excel or libre office.
One possible solution we found is:

**=SUMIF(Sheet2.A2:A10;"test1";Sheet2.C2:C10)**

But this will work when there are not so many different DataOrigin as this would need to be changed for each entry. However I will have to deal with several hundred DataOrigin entries.

The output I would need would look like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/56320731010f969d27d378bba268efe9.png).

Does any kind soul face this problem before? The table I will have to do this on has a few thousand rows.

Answer (score -1):

So with a friend we came to this solution in libre office:

**=SUMIF(Sheet2.A2:A16;A2;Sheet2.C2:C16)**

It seems to work, but I am not sure if it's error free, I tried it with mixing the DataOrigin column up and adding more data and it seems to work.